# How complex numbers can be compared in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in an inner product space over the complex field

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is given by
$|\langle x,y \rangle| \leqslant  \|x\| \|y\|,\, x,y\in V$ . My question is that over the complex fields the RHS of the inequality will be a complex number. But we know that complex numbers cannot be compared. Then how is it possible to compare them in this inequality?

Comment: For all $x\neq 0$, even for a complex vector, we have $\|x\|>0$ is real and positive.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb C^n$, the RHS is a non-negative real number, since$$\|(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n)\rVert=\sqrt{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2}.$$

Comment: But norm of x is defined as square root of inner product of x and x . If the field is C then the inner product will also be in C

Comment: In $\Bbb C^n$, the standard inner product is$$\langle(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n),(w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n)\rangle=z_1\overline{w_1}+z_2\overline{w_2}+\cdots+z_n\overline{w_n};$$in particular, if $z,w\in\Bbb C$, $\langle z,w\rangle=z\overline w$. So, $\langle z,z\rangle=z\overline z=|z|^2$ and therefore $\|z\|=|z|$. If you are working with another inner product, then tell us which inner product is that.

Comment: There is an inner product space Mm×n (C). The inner product is defined in the following page https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379513005867

Comment: You can read on page 3 of that article that “any given inner product $\langle,\cdots,\cdot\rangle$ on $M_n(\Bbb C)$ is a bounded sesquilinear form on $M_n(\Bbb C)$”. If $B$ is such a sesquilinear form, then, since it is sesquilinear, $B(M,M)\in[0,\infty)$, for every $M\in M_n(\Bbb C)$.

Comment: I am just a beginner in this topic. I have no idea about sesquilinear forms. I just saw an example of an inner product space over C so as to clarify my doubt. Can you please elaborate your explanation

Comment: What I wrote in my previous comment about $B(M,M)$ being always a non-negative real number is not correct (but it is always real). Anyway, it is [part of the definition of inner product on a complex space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Complex_coordinate_space) that you always have $\langle M,M\rangle\geqslant0$.

Comment: So does that mean that norms of any inner product spaces belong to real number set, it will never be a complex number with non zero imaginary part?

Comment: No, **never**.${}$

Comment: Do you mean it will never be complex, right?

Comment: I mean that the norms will **always** be non-negative real numbers.

Comment: Okay. Thankyou so much for your assistance

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.